# Pointers needed in debugging pstack backtrace

Tags: java

I need help in debugging a pstack backtrace:

```
    App_crash debugging report
    Program: java_vm
    Process ID: 16951
    Thread ID: 22
    Received signal: 11

    Application Debugging Data
    --------------------------
    > /usr/bin/pstack 16951> 
    16951:  java_vm 
    -----------------  lwp# 1 / thread# 1  --------------------
     ff2cced0 read     (b, ffbf9d6f, 1)

     fedb014c JVM_Read (b, ffbf9d6f, 1, ff18a800, ff181e38, 290a0) + dc
     fe8937f8 ???????? (2915c, ff184c58, 400, fed26bd0, 20854, 10b03e0) + ffffffffffae3788
     fe891664 Java_java_io_FileInputStream_read (fe8b4000, fe8b58a4, 5c0, 229c0, 104a990, 400) + 30
     f900bc20 * java/io/FileInputStream.read()I+18736
     f900bbc4 * java/io/FileInputStream.read()I+0
     f90058b8 * java/io/DataInputStream.readInt()I+4 (line 353)
     f90058b8 * sun/plugin/navig/motif/Plugin.doit()V+157 (line 173)
     f9005764 * sun/plugin/navig/motif/Plugin.start(Z)V+213 (line 104)
     f9000218 * StubRoutines (1)
     fecdd520 __1cJJavaCallsLcall_helper6FpnJJavaValue_pnMmethodHandle_pnRJavaCallArguments_pnGThread__v_ (0, 290a0, ffbfa280, ffbfa1b8, 29674, 0) + 5b8
     fedb9cc4 jni_CallStaticVoidMethod (ff188a24, ff181820, 29674, 290a0, 0, 29270) + 514
     0001185c main     (fecef5f8, aa10d, 1, ff184c58, fedb97b0, 22e88) + 710
     00010c88 _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + 108

    ..........

    -----------------  lwp# 22 / thread# 22  --------------------
     f9014854 * java/net/HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFieldDate(Ljava/lang/String;J)J+9 (line 440)
     f90058fc * java/net/URLConnection.getExpiration()J+4 (line 502)
     f90058fc * sun/plugin/cache/CachedFileLoader.download()Z+93 (line 301)
     f90057a8 * sun/plugin/cache/CachedFileLoader.load()Lsun/plugin/cache/CachedFile;+26 (line 119)
     f9005874 * sun/plugin/cache/FileCache.get(Ljava/net/URL;)Lsun/plugin/cache/CachedFile;+52 (line 136)
     f9005874 * sun/plugin/cache/PluginCacheHandler.get(Ljava/net/URI;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/net/CacheResponse;+22 (line 87)
     f9005874 * sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.plainConnect()V+54 (line 743)
     f9005764 * sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.connect()V+1 (line 716)
     f9005764 * sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()Ljava/io/InputStream;+139 (line 960)
     f9005874 * java/net/HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode()I+16 (line 367)
     f90058b8 * sun/applet/AppletClassLoader.getBytes(Ljava/net/URL;)[B+18 (line 313)
     f9005874 * sun/applet/AppletClassLoader.access$100(Ljava/net/URL;)[B+1 (line 50)
     f9005874 * sun/applet/AppletClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+77 (line 197)
     f9000218 * StubRoutines (1)
     fecdd520 __1cJJavaCallsLcall_helper6FpnJJavaValue_pnMmethodHandle_pnRJavaCallArguments_pnGThread__v_ (1, 2f26c8, f707f134, f707f038, f707f138, 0) + 5b8
     feceda04 JVM_DoPrivileged (2f2784, 1, 2f28b0, 4, c, 2f28ac) + 560
     fe88ee84 Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedExceptionAction_2Ljava_security_AccessControlContext_2 (2f2784, f707f450, f707f4dc, f707f4d8, f0, b801fa) + 14
     f900bc20 * java/security/AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
     f900bbc4 * java/security/AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
     f9005874 * sun/applet/AppletClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+107 (line 187)
     f9005874 * java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+43 (line 307)
     f9005874 * sun/applet/AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;+36 (line 145)
     f9005874 * java/lang/ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+3 (line 252)
     f9005874 * sun/applet/AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+105 (line 659)
     f9005874 * sun/applet/AppletPanel.createApplet(Lsun/applet/AppletClassLoader;)Ljava/applet/Applet;+83 (line 723)
     f9005874 * sun/plugin/AppletViewer.createApplet(Lsun/applet/AppletClassLoader;)Ljava/applet/Applet;+9 (line 1813)
     f9005874 * sun/applet/AppletPanel.runLoader()V+65 (line 652)
     f9005764 * sun/applet/AppletPanel.run()V+13 (line 326)
     f9005c2c * java/lang/Thread.run()V+11 (line 595)
     f9000218 * StubRoutines (1)
     fecdd520 __1cJJavaCallsLcall_helper6FpnJJavaValue_pnMmethodHandle_pnRJavaCallArguments_pnGThread__v_ (1, 2f26c8, f707fc18, f707fb38, f707fc1c, 0) + 5b8
     fecf4f74 __1cJJavaCallsMcall_virtual6FpnJJavaValue_nGHandle_nLKlassHandle_nMsymbolHandle_5pnGThread__v_ (5964, 2f26c8, 2f2898, 2f28a4, 2f2c84, cd026210) + 18c
     fecf4dd0 __1cMthread_entry6FpnKJavaThread_pnGThread__v_ (cd026210, 2f26c8, ff197cf4, d5812af8, 2f2898, ff1977e0) + 12c
     fecf4c54 __1cKJavaThreadDrun6M_v_ (2f26c8, 4c00, ff18639c, 0, 6400, ff16e000) + 2d0
     ff03dabc __1cG_start6Fpv_0_ (2f26c8, ff188a5c, ff1818ec, 0, 340c, ff16e000) + 200
```

Any pointers will help...

There is some links about Received signal 11,  but it is not very clear.  It talks about segmentation fault etc., but can someone throw more insight into how to fix this issue.  I think the correct JDK versions etc have been installed.  We tried this out.  Don't know what else could be wrong?